# Java Apache CXF for handling plain XML

Tags: xml, apache, web-services, soap

I have a service which currently uses SOAP as protocol and client has been implemented using Apache cxf. It uses JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and ClientProxy  for proxy generation, WSS4JOutInterceptor/WSS4JInInterceptor as encryption and logging handler.

Now, we would want to extend this service to handle plain XML objects also in the same way (encryption, logging is required in this case also). Is there a way I can use these already used library functions to do what I want. Or do we have other apache libraries that are similar to these and work for plain XML objects?

Comment: I thought SOAP is a messaging protocol which uses XML.
I know JAXB can help me marshal/unmarshal XML/Java objects but I am not sure how can I create XML client and handlers with it.

Comment: Sorry wrote my comment in a hurry this morning. SOAP is a protocol but it does not have to use XML. You can use JSON in SOAP though like I said why would you want to do that? Anyways I am not quite following your question you have implemented a client in CXF? Now you want to implement another client?

Comment: We have implemented soap client using CXF. Now we want to implement client and handlers for XML. I hope I am little clear now.